# Devbridge autocomplete serviceUrl and lookup

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Problem: 
If I use `serviceUrl`, Devbridge autocomplete works fine, but doesn't sort the suggestions list, because I didn't implement search method on server side.

I would prefer to use sort on client side. `look up` attribute works fine, but only with local array.

First of all, the server side returns proper answer with json formatting that was suggested by devbridge.
So I implemented the function that fetchs data and put it into array, then pass it to `lookup`.

```
    var jsonData= (function() {
    var result;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'index.php?option=com_crowdfunding&format=raw&task=project.loadLocations',
        dataType:'json',
        async:true,
        success:function(data){
            result = data;
        }
    });
    return result;
})();


jQuery('#autocomplete-ajax').autocomplete({
    lookup:jsonData,
```

I figured out that the problem is the script executes further while there is no data from server. I thought that attribute `async:false` would solve all my problems, but I faced with the issues that the arribute have been already depreciated and I don't have any idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var jsonData= (function() {
        var result;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'index.php?option=com_crowdfunding&format=raw&task=project.loadLocations',
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data){
               result = data;
            }
        });
        return result;
    });
    jQuery('#autocomplete-ajax').autocomplete({
        lookup:jsonData,
    }
});
```